# c# regular expression search, format the search prase if boolean AND,OR,NOT presents

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i need to do search engine, its like string matching, if the search string consists of boolean text like AND,OR,NOT i have to format the search string according to the boolean logic..

eg:- search string is **sachin and lara or ponting**, now i have to format the string without boolean keywords but the it accepts the **and,or,not** logics.

http://www.csa.com/help/Search_Tools/boolean_operators.html

already i posted one qustion regarding this , but now i have idea about the regular expression...

please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Need a lot more info for this to be an answerable question

Comment: Looking to your answer I'm assuming you are using C# / .Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some kind of capturing, like:

`(?<Operator>(AND|OR|NOT))`

But named captures are only in .Net: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: string s=abcd AND efgh; bool reslt=Regex.IsMatch(s,"?<Operator>(AND|OR|NOT)"); im getting exception as Parsing "?<Operator>(AND|OR|NOT)" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing...

Comment: You are starting with a `?`, but you should start with a `(?` and you should end with an `)`

Comment: thanx,if the search string as **aaa and bbb or ccc not ddd** now i have to change that string into valid search string.. is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, that is possible with .Net regex. Just check this example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx#CodeSpippet2